# Find the Laurent series for $f(z)= (z^5)/((z^2) -2)^2$.

Tags: complex-analysis

$$f(z)= \frac{z^5}{(z^2 -2)^2} $$

My difficulty is $z^5$.I did not find any similar example.
Photography : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjpNb.jpg

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Around which point? In what annulus? If it's around $0$, you can just factor $z^5$ out.

Comment: About the point sqrt(2).

Comment: And what annulus?

Comment: I don't know. The question don't informs the annulus. But, the  point is sqrt(2) and -sqrt(2). The question asks to find the annulus.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/PX2VUPz.jpg

Answer (score 3):

If you can find the Laurent series for $\frac{1}{(z^2-2)^2}$ about the point $z_0=\sqrt{2}$, then note that 
$$
z^5=\Big((z-z_0)+z_0\Big)^5=(z-z_0)^5+5z_0(z-z_0)^4+\dots+5z_0^4(z-z_0)+z_0^5
$$

Comment: Is there some general formula for z5=((z−z0)+z0)5 ?

Comment: @Thamires Yes, this is the Binomial Theorem. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Comment: Ok, but, is there some formula general for z^5 in serie ?

Comment: @Thamires I'm not sure I understand your question. Would you mind elaborating a bit more on what you want a more general formula for?

Comment: I'm not American, my English is not very good. I thought I needed to write z^5 in summation. But, I think it's enough to write the terms. I found the serie for 1/(z^2−2)^2. Check if it is correct, in this link, please : http://i.imgur.com/PX2VUPz.jpg